# Variable importance in random forest regression: scaled or unscaled

Tags: regression, random-forest, importance

If I want to use the original random forest variable importance measure Mean Decrease in Accuracy [1] (which can be the Increase in MSE, for example) when applying random forest regression, should I use the scaled variable importance [2], where the the raw importance is divided by its standard error or rather the unscaled importance?

Strobl et al. suggest not to use the scaled variable importance[3], because it "induces a dependence on the number of trees but at the same time inverts the dependence on the sample size" [4]. On the other hand in most standard implemenations of random forest variable importance it is scaled by default, as for example in [2].

Do you know any other than the cited references, which compare the scaled and unscaled random forest variable importance especially for regression?

**References:** 
[1] Breiman, Leo. "Random forests." Machine learning 45.1 (2001): 5-32. 
[2] https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/importance 
[3] Strobl C, Zeileis A: Danger: High Power! – Exploring the Statistical Properties of a Test for Random Forest Variable Importance. Proceedings of the 18th International Conference on Computational Statistics, Porto, Portugal 2008. 
[4] Strobl, Carolin, et al. "Conditional variable importance for random forests." BMC bioinformatics 9.1 (2008): 307. Page 6.